# Fill div with image without stretching

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image with high resolution (`width: 5540px, height: 2680px`), and I need 
this image to cover an entire div (this div goes full width and 80% of height). This image is displayed on screens with resolutions of 768px till 1600px.

When I use `background-size: cover`, the image goes full width but the bottom part is cut off.

When I use `background-size: contain`, the image is resized to fit the height but the width isn't entirely filled.

When I user `background-size: 100%`, the image fill the entire div, but gets stretch out.

Is there any way to do that or do I need to resize the image (for example, resize image to 1600px (width) because this image is only displayed on screens with width from 768px to 1600px)?

Comment: can you add the page url

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do. `background-size: cover` will cover the div with the image, while keeping the image proportionate. Are you saying you want the image to be squished to match the dimensions of the div?

Comment: @Ram, The page has not yet been published.

Comment: Hi, @Santi. When I use background-size: cover, the bottom of the image gets cut off. I want the image to occupy the entire div, without stretching or been cut off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Image Liquid js for it. 
https://github.com/karacas/imgLiquid

Hope it will help you...

Answer (score 1):

If your original image is 5540x2680px, you should probably start by resizing it manually, because that's just to much to load if you want to display it at max. 1600px width.

For the resizing it then depends on the content of the image. Since the ratios you mentioned are almost similar, I guess your best bet is to go with background-size:cover and reposition it using background-position property.

eg

```
background-position: center bottom;
```

because you mentioned that the bottom was cut off.

Answer (score 0):

Since the image is wider than it is high, set the height to `100%` and the width to `auto`:

```
background-size: auto 100%;
```

Basic example:

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: url('http://lorempizza.com/1000/600') scroll no-repeat center;
  
  /* Set it to be 100% height, with an auto width */
  background-size: auto 100%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

If it was the other way around, with the height being larger that the width, you'd just switch them:

```
background-size: 100% auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is tested and working solution.**

What you need is:

Parent div to be:

```
position: relative; overflow: hidden;
```

And image:

```
img {
  bottom: -5000px;
  left: -5000px;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: -5000px;
  top: -5000px;
}
```

This will center the image no matter what and keep its proportions. And please please please **do not use image which is width: 5540px, height: 2680px**, unless this is the size of your container where you putting it. **It will add substantially to your page load and its considered bad practice.** Better resize the image to needed size.

Comment: Hi, @Tauciokas. So the better way is to resize the image to be width 1600px and height 768px, which is the div's size?

Comment: Yes and then use CSS above. This will center your image no matter whats the size of the container

Answer (score 0):

### Fill div with image without stretching

*using this method you can easily fit image*

put these code lines into your image box css class

```
object-fit: cover;
height: 300px;
width: 270px;
object-position: center center;
```

```css
.gallery-section .inner-width .container{
 width: 1280px;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 left: 10%;
 right: 10%;
 margin: auto;
}

.gallery-section .inner-width .container .box{
 position: relative;
 width: 270px;
 height: 300px;
 background: #277bde;
 margin: 3px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 display: inline-block; 
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: round;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 10px;object-fit: cover;


}

.gallery-section .inner-width .container .box .imgBox{
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;

}

.gallery-section .inner-width .container .box .imgBox img{  /*this is the code for fitting image*/
 object-fit: cover;
 height: 300px;
 width: 270px;
 object-position: center center;

}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-section">
  <div class="inner-width">

      <div class="container">
        <div class="box">
          <div class="imgBox">
            <img class="" src="img/news-01.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <div class="imgBox">
            <img class="" src="img/news-01.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <div class="imgBox">
            <img class="" src="img/news-01.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
</div>
```